# How to override Rails 3.1 "Routing Error" when using engines with glob routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm converting a legacy app to Rails 3.1.  The new app uses an engine that provides a glob route:

```
# myengine/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match 'foo/bar/*path' => 'myengine/foobar#index', :format => false
end
```

The legacy app used a final catchall wildcard route to provide custom handling (rather than the familiar Rails "Routing Error" page) for otherwise unmatched routes:

```
# myapp/config/routes.rb
Myapp::application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  match '*path' => 'failures#index', :format => false
end
```

Somehow this catchall route is interfering with the engine's route.  If I comment out the app's catchall route, the engine's route works fine.  But if I leave it in the engine route is never matched and the app's catchall route to `failures#index` is used instead:

```
Started GET "/foo/bar//projects/x/vol1/prod22/9907042031/9907042031.aff/ImageProperties.xml" for 10.71.1.136 at 2011-08-02 15:46:48 -0700
  Processing by FailuresController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"path"=>"foo/bar/projects/x/vol1/prod22/9907042031/9907042031.aff/ImageProperties.xml"}
Rendered failures/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 46.9ms)
```

How would one override the default Rails 3.1 routing error handler without breaking engine routes?

Comment: Good question.  By the way, the Rails 3 catch-all route can be formatted like: `match '*path', :to => 'docs#not_found'` now

Comment: have you tried this? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from

Comment: It seems this behavior is a known bug in Rails 3.x (see Andre Andre Pankratz's 19 Mar 2011 comment here: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4444-can-no-longer-rescue_from-actioncontrollerroutingerror) and his gem that works around the bug here (https://github.com/vidibus/vidibus-routing_error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle this *used to be* `rescue_from` and a custom error handler, rather than with an engines-hostile catchall route.  However, [custom error handlers are no longer supported in Rails 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671) and this likely won't be fixed until Rails 3.2, if ever.  If you need custom error handling and you use engines with routes, the [`vidibus-routing_error`](https://github.com/vidibus/vidibus-routing_error) gem provides a workaround.

Another option is to put your custom error handler into a Rack endpoint at the bottom of your stack.